# How to create procedure for pagging in sql server with OFFSET?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure to fetch data by `PageIndex` and `PageSize` using OFFSET ROWS

Comment: _I want to..._ What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` for tech number of rows from index. Demo is here

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_StudentSelectPaging]
@PageIndex          INT=1,
@PageSize           INT=10 
AS 
BEGIN   

   SET NOCOUNT ON;  
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumber,[RecordCount]=COUNT(*) OVER(),
         Id,Name,City   
   FROM (
        SELECT          
            ISNULL(Id,0) AS Id,
            ISNULL(Name,0) AS Name,             
            ISNULL(City,'') AS City     
        FROM F_Posts P      
   ) AS tmpTable
   ORDER BY ISNULL(Id,1) DESC       

   OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageIndex-1) ROWS   
   FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;              
END
```

Note:  `OFFSET` is only supported in the higher versions than SQL Server R2 2008.